# ExtJS propertygrid resizable columns?

Tags: extjs, properties, header, resize, grid

I want the users to be able to resize the Value column of my property grid but no luck with the settings. Tried all kinds of grid column properties that came to my mind like:

```
fixed: false,
resizable: true
```

- they don't work. Googled but didn't find anything related to my issue. I'm only able to resize it programatically with this code in the afterrender listener:

```
this.columns[0].setWidth(160);
```

Comment: Have you tried the width property for the column?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is NOT resizing the columns by code, I want to be able to drag and resize with the mouse, but ExtJS doesn't show me the resize handles. I guess I didn't make it clear in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The correct config for this would appear to be [`enableColumnResize: true`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.Grid-cfg-enableColumnResize), but in my brief testing it does not appear to change the behavior. In fact, that config is documented as defaulting to `true`, which would imply that it's not working by default. I think this might be a bug in Ext, so you might want to follow up in the [Sencha forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/) if you can't get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After posting my question here, I found 2 posts in their forum and no replies by the pros. I'm actually expecting a workaround here.. someone might have found a way already.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this one.
This works for me:

```
Ext.require('Ext.grid.property.HeaderContainer', function(){
    Ext.override(Ext.grid.property.HeaderContainer, {
        constructor: function() {
            //enable resizing
            this.enableColumnResize = true;
            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    });
});
```